# Less repetitious way to do explicit template instantiation (ETIs)? (without macros)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, explicit-instantiation

Small example problem:

```
// foo.h
template <typename S>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    void Bar ();
};
```

Both `S` and `T` can be either `char` or `int`. 'Seems like an easy list to maintain, but here's the code:

```
// foo.cpp
template <typename S>
template <typename T>
void Foo<S>::
    Bar ()
    {
        // uses S and T
    }

template class Foo<int>;
template class Foo<char>;
template void Foo<int>::Bar<int>();
template void Foo<int>::Bar<char>();
template void Foo<char>::Bar<int>();
template void Foo<char>::Bar<char>();
```

And just to make it a complete example:

```
// main.cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main ()
{
    // uses all the Foo/Bar permutations
}
```

In my real-world example I have 2 outer types and 5 inner types for 2 methods, resulting in 2 + 3 * 2 * 5 = 32 ETIs!

I understand that when using ETIs I need to maintain a list of used arguments, but do I really need to maintain all the permutations?

Comment: With variadic template you might **implicit** instantiate them... Why do you want all those explicit instantiations?

Comment: @Jarod42, can we use implicit instantiation safely? ie. If I make a templated function that basically does the permutation calls, can I be sure that it won't be optimised out before the instantiation? eg. a const method where the return value is being ignored? I guess that this is the question I should've asked...

Comment: @Elliott The calls might be optimized away but not the instantiated templates.

Comment: Implicit instantiations doesn't have to be part of `.obj`. So it is not reliable and might depends of compiler, but there are instantiated to check validity for example, that's also why I asked purpose of wanted ETIs.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks for your help. I use ETIs to reduce compile time of other translation units (I wasn't aware of another reason). I'm a little confused on your last comment. If you were to answer with a safe way to use implicit instantiation (at least for the above example), then I'd certainly accept that.

Comment: @idmean, thanks. That would be ideal. I'd accept that as an answer with a little explanation as to why we can be use that the instantiation is reliable. Cheers.

Comment: @Jaord42 is right, of course. I didn't think this through and I don't think there is a way without using macros, sorry. Please see the linked question above.